# ipad popover problem

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, ios-simulator, uipopovercontroller

I have one **delegate** file, one **View Controller** and one **UIPopoverController**

My PopoverController is defined in delegate file.

when I click on the view controller's button, the popover is shown.

The view controller also contains one method named "**refreshviewnow**".

When I click on the PopoverController "submit button", I want to call that **refreshviewnow** function.

What should I have to write on submit button event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer now.

add **observer** in **View Controller** file for method **refreshviewnow**.

post the notification when popover is going to dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "submit button" *(maybe you should post some of the code you are using)*, but if you are trying to call a method that is in the same controller, you would do it like this:

```
- (void) methodToDisplayPopover
{
    [self refreshViewNow];
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
MySecondView *second = [[MySecondView alloc] init];
[second refreshViewNow];
[second release];
```

Comment: both are in different .m file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure and set the delegate property of the PopoverController to the View Controller.  Then in the "submit button" you can invoke the method on the delegate.

```
- (void) submit {
   [delegate refreshAction];
}
```

Good Luck.

Comment: this is not helping me i dont know why but here is some problem 
THanks but try to help me out from this q.